# How do I make arrow keys work in MIT Scheme interpreter?

Tags: macos, terminal, mit-scheme

I have installed MIT Scheme from the instructions [here](https://wiki.umn.edu/CSCI1901/InstallingMITScheme) on my laptop running Yosemite. I can get the `scheme` interpreter from Terminal, but none of my arrow keys seem to working. For any typing mistakes I make I cannot go back and correct it. I have to use backspace or re-type the whole thing.

Left arrow prints `^[[D`

Right arrow prints `^[[C`

Up arrow prints `^[[A`

Down arrow prints `^[[B`

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screnshot showing arrow keys at work, not]

Comment: As it is said in the page you linked, you should use [Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/) to interact with the Scheme interpreter. For a more friendly interaction, you could also use [Racket](http://racket-lang.org) instead of Scheme, with its own IDE.

Comment: So, there is no other way to make it work in Terminal? Thanks for the tip of Racket. I will start using that instead.

Comment: As you said, in terminal you have to use backspace or re-type the whole thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/). Which is a wrap around the [Readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline). After installing in your system, just run as:

```
$ rlwrap mit-scheme
```

And it should work. There is a [tutorial](http://rayhightower.com/blog/2015/03/19/using-rlwrap-with-mit-scheme-repl/).

Even if it can be done, it doesn't mean you should. MIT-scheme already 
provides the Edwin editor, which is an emacs like editor, that works great. I use it everyday. It also comes with a graphical debugger. Your other options would be emacs+Geiser (or Greg's [racket-mode](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode)), with guile or racket. Or DrRacket which is an IDE, with many aids for learning.

Comment: hey, how do I start Edwin editor? I am doing SICP, thats the reason I have installed MIT Scheme. If you can share some resources/link about MIT Scheme, editor, debugger etc then it would be great.

Comment: to start it directly from the command line `$ mit-scheme --edit`  Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/index.html)

Comment: docs are [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-user/Edwin.html#Edwin) now 

Comment: My scheme prompt is just `scheme` as I installed diff version using [this](https://jacksonisaac.com/2014/03/25/installing-scheme-on-mac-os-x/), so starting the editor is `scheme --edit`. `mit-scheme --edit` returns `command not found: mit-scheme` which through me for a minute. In case anyone else runs into this...